# Place text on top of other CALayer in drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, drawrect

I am trying to show text above `CALayer` but somehow I am not able to achieve it. I have used following code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    self.layer.sublayers = nil;
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

    // Code to show grid lines clipped

    CGRect overallRectForBarItem = CGRectMake(20, 20, 176, 35);
    CAShapeLayer *barItemShape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    barItemShape.frame = overallRectForBarItem;
    barItemShape.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:overallRectForBarItem].CGPath;
    barItemShape.strokeColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    barItemShape.fillColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    [self.layer addSublayer:barItemShape];

    [self drawTextForBarItem:@"TESTING" inRect:CGRectMake(100, 40, 35, 0)];

    // Other code clipped

    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}

-(void) drawTextForBarItem:(NSString*)barItemTitle inRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    float actualFontSize = 14.0;
    UIFont *font = [ISUtility getSystemFont:actualFontSize];
    CGSize size = [barItemTitle sizeWithFont:font];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy] autorelease];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    [barItemTitle drawInRect:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y - size.height/2, rect.size.width, size.height) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle}];
}
```

Following is the screen shot of simulator.[image: Screenshot]

I have also tried `zPosition` but no use.

```
barItemShape.zPosition = -1000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most possible cause of you issue is that you creating `CGContextRef` but adding sublayer when you need to draw lightgray rectangle. I think, that it would be more consistant to draw your rectange with CoreGraphics functions and that draw your text.

To be more detailed, it seems that you drawing text in current layer but adding sublayer that will be above your text.

For instance, you can use this code to give it a try:

```
UIColor * redColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, redColor.CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
```

Comment: Do you have any example to draw rectangle using `CoreGraphics`

Comment: I've edited my post. Also you can try some useful base examples [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32283/core-graphics-tutorial-lines-rectangles-and-gradients)

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue while using `CoreGraphics` with `CALayer`. No ?

Comment: Your edit worked but I have bunch of code written already in CALayer. Please provide solution that can work using both CG and CALayer.

Comment: I think it shouldn't. Also, you can try to replace `[self.layer addSublayer:barItemShape];` with `[barItemShape drawInContext:ctx];`

Comment: I tried `drawInContext` but it is not showing anything except Text

Comment: As I see, your code is a bit inconsistency. I didn't see any proper way to draw your CALayer in CGContext without bunch of code. So I think you should change text drawing and use something else instead of just calling `drawInRect` or use another way to draw you rectangle or implement `- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)theLayer inContext:(CGContextRef)theContext`.

Comment: Finally I have used `CoreGraphics` to add Bars in `UIView`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50760/discussion-between-faisal-ali-and-crostek)